# Is it okay to get partial funding for a conference from two institutions?

Tags: conference, ethics, funding

Is it possible (and legal) to get funding from both the host university and the university the student is from, for overseas conferences?

To elaborate, let's say I (a student) am going for an overseas conference. My home university is able to fund me (but only partially). The host university is also providing funding (but limited funds, so I am assuming it is also partial funding). Is it possible to apply for both these fundings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say you could apply, yes, but you should mention that you also applied for the other funding. To make sure that you don't run into problems, I would first discuss it with the responsible people at both institutes, as the rules might differ from conference to conference, institute to institute, depending on country, etc.
Then, I would write down a short statement of cost. For example:

- Flight:  500
- Hotel stay: 350
- Conference fee: 100
- Meals (if not included in hotel cost): 50

Total: 1000.

For this cost, student ... received partial funding from institute A: XXX and from institute B: YYY.

Make sure that $XXX + YYY \leq 1000$ and then have both institutes sign it. This should put you on the safe side, as you can use it to prove that both institutes knew about the other partial funding and that you weren't "overfunded". Of course it would be best to have an estimate of the costs beforehand and to discuss these things also before you receive money, so once again: Go talk to the people responsible.

And I hope that it's clear that you should, under no circumstances, get overfunded here. Don't risk it for a few bucks, this might strongly backfire once someone finds out.

Comment: This is certainly a safe approach, but maybe unnecessarily cautious.  If one institute offers you partial funding, I think they would assume the rest is probably coming from some other institution.  Typically you sign a form saying you are not being doubly reimbursed and that is the end of it.  Of course, you should save the records of your expenditures and reimbursements just in case anyone asks in the future.

Comment: @NateEldredge - That would make a constructive answer.

Comment: I have done this before and did it basically exactly as described.  I actually had three funding sources (one fund at one university, and two separate pots of money at another) and it went fine.  It's easier, I feel, if they're collectively offering far more than you need, so you can get the flight from source A, and the hotel and conference fees from Source B.  Less paperwork than if you need to split an expense between the two sources, but may not always be possible.